# How to only set one table row "table-active" at a time?

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a web app that utilizes the Bootstrap table row. I am trying to have it where when the user clicks on the row, it will become `table-active`. Currently, I have it setup where it highlights not one but numerous rows when clicked. I am trying to find the most effiecient way of coding this all within jquery.

**Javascript:**

```
    $(".table tr").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("table-active");
    });
```

Comment: Any error on console?

Answer (score 3):

Just turn the class off every row first, then toggle it onto the clicked one:

```
$(".table tr").click(function() {
  $(".table tr").removeClass("table-active");
  $(this).toggleClass("table-active");
});
```